# Would like to take a photo with 5 cameras simultaneously and send to dropbox or eyefi

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I'd like to set up a station in a warehouse to take photos of a pallet before it is shipped.  5 cameras total, one for each side of the pallet and one for a top view.  The idea is to roll the pallet into place, press one button to trigger all five cameras, and have the photos automatically load to the cloud via an eyefi sd card or directly through a computer into dropbox.
So far the best solution suggested has been Nikon P7800 cameras with wr-r10 and wr-t10 remote controls.  Will these cameras stay powered on if they are connected to AC adapters?  It would be to difficult to turn on all five cameras manually each time a photo was taken, as they are taken throughout the day.

Maybe there is a less expensive solution?

Comment: Your requirements aren't very clear. Do you need the 12MP resolution of the Nikon P7800, or would something more like a webcam work? Do you need the images to be taken at precisely the same moment, or just at about the same time? Webcams would be both less expensive and a lot easier to work with.

Comment: GoPro. Or talk to someone who actually knows something about your industry and technology for it (i.e. warehouse and DC machine vision solutions, etc.). That is all quite off topic here though.

Comment: I think the Nikon P7800 was recommended because it was the cheapest camera that would work with the wr-r10 and wr-t10.  I think any decent image would work, we currently take the photos manually with our phones. The images don't need to be taken precisely at the same moment, just about the same time would work.  The key feature would be ease of use, pressing one button to take five photos and send them to the cloud simultaneously would save a lot of time.  Thank you for the replies @caleb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this application, I'd lean toward some kind of webcam for the following reason:

- **choice:** There's a huge selection of webcams available in different resolutions and at different price points, so it shouldn't be hard to find an effective solution that will still keep the cost down.
- **ease of use:** Many webcams have built-in web servers, so that "taking a picture" is really as simple as making a HTTP request. Given your requirements, there's no need for special software for synchronizing the camera's -- just pull images from all five cameras at the same time.
- **interchangeability:** Building a solution with webcams will make it easy to avoid being locked into one vendor or system. If one of the cameras stops working, or if you just want to upgrade it, it'll be very easy to replace it with a different camera and update your system to use the new one.
- **always on:** Webcams are usually designed so that they're always on, so you won't have any problem with the cameras turning themselves off or buying special AC adapters.
- **low maintenance:** Most webcams have simple optical systems that don't require any focus or aperture adjustments. They're plug and play.

Software for remotely controlling more complex cameras exists, but it doesn't sound like you need the kind of control that those cameras would afford. Apply the KISS principle and go with the simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

For the price tag ([dpreview lists $598.00 per unit](http://www.dpreview.com/products/Nikon/compacts/nikon_cpp7800) and [ebay uk auctions](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR10.TRC0.A0.H0.Xnikon+p7800.TRS0&_nkw=nikon+p7800&_sacat=0) aren't hugely different) there will definitely be many cheaper options available if your concern is cost.

At this point much cheaper options for 12mp wifi enabled cameras like GoPro clones at around £40 ukp which could be triggered over wi-fi via some kind of control system (either pc or embedded box like raspberry pi.)

Even a fully blown (automated) system would probably be cheaper than the price you're looking at and wouldn't require any human interaction, just roll the pallet over a sensor and job done - you should talk to a specialist in the field to look at solutions that fit your needs better.

*prices as of 6th February 2016.*

Comment: _you should talk to a specialist in the field to look at solutions that fit your needs better._ - Exactly. This isn't the place either.